# How to make the picker component re-render its items properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-effect, use-state

I have two pickers (@react-native-community/picker) in a form, one field for state and other for city.

```
<StyledPicker
  key="statePicker"
  selectedValue={values.state}
  onValueChange={(value, id) => {
    setFieldValue('state', value);

    setState(values.state);
    console.log(state);
  }}
>
  {stateList.length > 0 &&
    stateList.map(stateEl => (
      <StyledPicker.Item
        key={stateEl.id}
        label={stateEl.name}
        value={stateEl.id}
      />
    ))}
</StyledPicker>
```

```
<StyledPicker
  key="cityPicker"
  selectedValue={values.city}
  onValueChange={(value, id) => {
    setFieldValue('city', value);
  }}
>
  {cityList.length > 0 &&
    cityList.map(cityEl => (
      <StyledPicker.Item
        key={cityEl.id}
        label={cityEl.name}
        value={cityEl.id}
      />
    ))}
</StyledPicker>
```

I have an API that gives me the list of the cities of each state, so everytime the user changes the state, I call a asynchronous function to get from the API the list of cities.

I made a state for the 'state' field to be used in a useEffect, that's why you see that 'setState' function in the onValueChange of the state picker. Every time I update the state, the api call happens and it returns me the list of cities.

```
useEffect(() => {
  async function loadCities() {
    try {
      const { data } = await api.get(`/states/${state}/cities`);

      const citiesFromAPI = data.map((resCity: any) => resCity.attributes);

      setCityList(citiesFromAPI);
    } catch (err) {
      Alert.alert('Something went wrong', 'Please, try again.');
      navigation.goBack();
    }
  }

  if (state) {
    loadCities();
  }
}, [navigation, state]);
```

The problem is, the list doesn't update after the value changed.
When the form component is mounted and I select a state from the picker for the first time, the list of cities doesn't change, and after selecting another state, the list updates to the previous values.

Ex: The form is mounted, the cities list is empty. I select Texas, the cities list is still empty. I select Missouri, and the cities list updates to the the cities of Texas.

I logged in the console to debug if the API was returning the right info when selected, and it is. When I select Texas, it gives me back the cities from Texas even on the first pick.

How can I make so that the list updates correctly after the state select?

Comment: do you have a githhub repo of this?

Comment: Unfortunatelly, this codebase and the API I'm using are proprietary. I'll try to make a codesnippet of it with a fake API.

Comment: that would help

Answer (score 1):

For people in the future with the same problem, I fixed it!

The problem was that both `setFieldValue` and my `setState` function (from `useState`) were synchronous.

So, when the `onChangeValue` event happened, both functions ran at the same time, and when that happened, the value for the "State" state wasn't updated yet.

I managed to fix it by using `setState(value)` with the value that came from the event, instead of `setState(values.state)` the value from the Formik object.